# Loading Properties.Settings from a different file at runtime

Tags: c#, app-config

Is there any way to load settings from a different file other than the default `App.config` file at runtime?  I'd like to do this after the default config file is loaded.

I use the `Settings.Settings` GUI in Visual Studio to create my `App.config` file for me.  The config file ends up looking like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="SnipetTester.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
      <applicationSettings>
        <SnipetTester.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="SettingSomething" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1234</value>
          </setting>
        </SnipetTester.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

In code, I'm able to access the settings like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Default setting value:  " + Properties.Settings.Default.SettingSomething);
```

The idea is that when the application is run, I should be able to specify a config file at run time and have the application load the config file into the `Properties.Settings.Default` object instead of using the default `app.config` file.  The formats of the config files would be the same, but the values of the settings would be different.

I know of a way to do this with the `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);`.  However, in the tests that I've run, it doesn't update the `Properties.Settings.Default` object to reflect the new values from the config file.

---

After thinking about this a bit longer, I've been able to come up with a solution that I like a little better.  I'm sure it has some pitfalls, but I think it'll work for what I need it to do.

Essentially, the `Properties.Settings` class is automatically generated by Visual Studio; it generates the code for the class for you.  I was able to find where the code was generated and add a few function calls to load a config file on its own.  Here's my addition:

```
internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase 
{
    //Parses a config file and loads its settings
    public void Load(string filename)
    {
        System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml = null;
        try
        {
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
            xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(text);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Pokemon catch statement (gotta catch 'em all)

            //If some exception occurs while loading the file,
            //assume either the file was unable to be read or
            //the config file is not in the right format.
            //The xml variable will be null and none of the
            //settings will be loaded.
        }

        if(xml != null)
        {
            foreach(System.Xml.Linq.XElement currentElement in xml.Elements())
            {
                switch (currentElement.Name.LocalName)
                {
                    case "userSettings":
                    case "applicationSettings":
                        foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement settingNamespace in currentElement.Elements())
                        {
                            if (settingNamespace.Name.LocalName == "SnipetTester.Properties.Settings")
                            {
                                foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement setting in settingNamespace.Elements())
                                {
                                    LoadSetting(setting);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Loads a setting based on it's xml representation in the config file
    private void LoadSetting(System.Xml.Linq.XElement setting)
    {
        string name = null, type = null, value = null;

        if (setting.Name.LocalName == "setting")
        {
            System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute xName = setting.Attribute("name");
            if (xName != null)
            {
                name = xName.Value;
            }

            System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute xSerialize = setting.Attribute("serializeAs");
            if (xSerialize != null)
            {
                type = xSerialize.Value;
            }

            System.Xml.Linq.XElement xValue = setting.Element("value");
            if (xValue != null)
            {
                value = xValue.Value;
            }
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == false &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(type) == false &&
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                //One of the pitfalls is that everytime you add a new
                //setting to the config file, you will need to add another
                //case to the switch statement.
                case "SettingSomething":
                    this[name] = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code I added exposes an `Properties.Settings.Load(string filename)` function.  The function accepts a config filename as a parameter.  It will parse the file and load up any settings it encounters in the config file.  To revert back to the original configuration, simply call `Properties.Settings.Reload()`.

Hope this might help someone else!

Comment: this seems really promising, but how can we use the types

Answer (score 1):

Look at using ExeConfigurationFileMap and ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration.

See [Cracking the Mysteries of .Net 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19675/Cracking-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration#t2_1)

> The ExeConfigurationFileMap allows you to specifically configure the
>   exact pathnames to machine, exe, roaming and local configuration
>   files, all together, or piecemeal, when calling
>   OpenMappedExeConfiguration(). You are not required to specify all
>   files, but all files will be identified and merged when the
>   Configuration object is created. When using
>   OpenMappedExeConfiguration, it is important to understand that all
>   levels of configuration up through the level you request will always
>   be merged. If you specify a custom exe and local configuration file,
>   but do not specify a machine and roaming file, the default machine and
>   roaming files will be found and merged with the specified exe and user
>   files. This can have unexpected consequences if the specified files
>   have not been kept properly in sync with default files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of the application:

1. Web Application & Windows Application - use the [configSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) xml attribute if you are willing to store the config files in the same folder (or subfolders) as the application
2. Create a [settings provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider.aspx) and also implement [IApplicationSettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Configuration.IApplicationSettingsProvider.aspx). Samples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20917/Creating-a-Custom-Settings-Provider) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136152/Create-a-Custom-Settings-Provider-to-Share-Setting). You might also need to use the [IConfigurationManagerInternal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.internal.iconfigurationmanagerinternal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface to replace the default .NET configuration manager. When implementing the provider don't forget to make a difference between user settings and application settings and the roaming profiles.

If you want to get started quickly just decompile the [LocalFileSettingsProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.localfilesettingsprovider.aspx) class (the default settings provider) and change it to your needs (you might find some useles code and might need to replicate all of the classes on which it depends).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can include the types so you don't need to manually update the source every time.

`private void LoadSetting(System.Xml.Linq.XElement setting)
        {
            string name = null, type = null;
            string value = null;

```
        if (setting.Name.LocalName == "setting")
        {
            System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute xName = setting.Attribute("name");
            if (xName != null)
            {
                name = xName.Value;
            }

            System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute xSerialize = setting.Attribute("serializeAs");
            if (xSerialize != null)
            {
                type = xSerialize.Value;
            }

            System.Xml.Linq.XElement xValue = setting.Element("value");
            if (xValue != null)
            {
                if (this[name].GetType() == typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection))
                {
                    foreach (string s in xValue.Element("ArrayOfString").Elements())
                    {
                        if (!((System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)this[name]).Contains(s))
                            ((System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)this[name]).Add(s);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    value = xValue.Value;
                }

                if (this[name].GetType() == typeof(int))
                {
                    this[name] = int.Parse(value);
                }
                else if (this[name].GetType() == typeof(bool))
                {
                    this[name] = bool.Parse(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    this[name] = value;
                }

            }
        }`
```

Comment: is it possible to handle this for arbitrary type