# Load user settings from file system

Tags: c#, settings, user.config

Is there a way to load a `user.config` file from an arbitrary location in the file system and refresh the content during run-time? I need to switch between different configuration files during run-time, but while the saving to any location works:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal) as Configuration;
config.SaveAs(filename);
```

I cannot find a way to load it back again. I cannot find methods to accomplish this and my workaround to replace the user.config file in the `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\"appname"` folder manually and then call `Properties.Settings.Default.Reload()` also does not work, although the file is correctly replaced (On the next application start it works, but after the reload-call there are no changes at all).

Comment: You can create a custom setting provider by overloading look for sample
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20917/Creating-a-Custom-Settings-Provider
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727654/loading-properties-settings-from-a-different-file-at-runtime